# How to divide students to 3 groups?

Tags: sql, firebird

I have a table contains

```
names | grades | ages
```

I order them by grades, this is the query:

```
select * from students order by grades
```

I want to divide them in three groups by percentage, the first group 35 percent according to the number of students and so on of the rest of the two groups

```
Group1 35%
group2 35%
group3 30%
```

How I divide them because the division according to the numbers of students and to these conditions:

1. group1 students who more than 22 old or more
2. group1 students who more than 25 old or more
3. group1 students who more than 30 old or more

This is the list of students

```
  names | Ages | Grades|
________________________
1 john  |  30  |   20  |
2 saur  |  24  |   15  |
3 laban |  22  |   20  |
4 steve |  26  |   16  |
5 sophie|  27  |   20  |
6 barry |  32  |   16  |
7 kevin |  31  |   19  |
8 jenny |  34  |   16  |
```

the group1 =8*35% /100=2.8, I take 2 students

the group2 =8*35% /100=2.8, I take 2 students

the group3 =8*30% /100=2.4, I take 2 students

This is my attempt

```
with tt1 as
         ( select id,names,grades,datediff(Year,Bdate,current_date) as
           ages from students 
         ),
     tt2 as 
         ( 
          select id,names,grades,
            case when ages >= 22 and ages < 99 then 1 else 0 end as group1, 
            case when ages >= 25 and ages < 99 then 1 else 0 end as group2,
            case when ages >= 30 and ages < 99 then 1 else 0 end as group3,            
          from tt1 order by grades desc )
          select * from tt2
```

Here the number of students became 5. How to do this in SQL? When I order them by grades, ages and divide them by percentage, I have this result:

```
  names | Ages | Grades|
________________________
1 john  |  30  |   20  |
2 sophie|  27  |   20  |
3 laban |  22  |   20  |
4 kevin |  31  |   19  |
5 jenny |  34  |   16  |
6 barry |  32  |   16  |
7 steve |  26  |   16  |
8 saur  |  24  |   15  |


8 students *35% =2.8 this is group1 = John,sophie
group2= kevin,jenny
group3= barry
```

I have only a 5 students who achieved the condition.

I divide by 5.

```
 5*35%=1.75 so group1 = 1 student
 5*35%=1.75 so group2 = 1 student 
 5*30%=1.5  so group3 = 1 student
```

The final result it will be

```
  names | Ages | Grades| Groups
_______________________________
1 john  |  30  |   20  |   1
2 sophie|  27  |   20  |   2
3 kevin |  31  |   19  |   3
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? It's much easier to get help when you post what you've tried, the results it yielded, and why specifically you reject what you got.

Comment: The problem is that the number of students is changing.

Comment: This is not a free write-my-code or even do-my-thinking site. You're generally expected to make some kind of effort to solve the problem first before asking for the (free) time of others to help you. We're here to _assist_ you, not to _replace_ you in writing the code. Please show us what you have done so far and what problem you're now facing. If you haven't started yet, please at least try. Thanks.

Comment: This is my attempt with  tt1 as (  select  id,
                           names,grades,datediff(Year,Bdate,current_date) as ages  from  students
                ),
        tt2 as (  select  id,names,grades,
                           case when ages >= 22 and ages < 99 then 1 else 0 end as group1,
                           case when ages >= 25 and ages < 99 then 1 else 0 end as group2,
                           case when ages >= 30 and ages < 99 then 1 else 0 end as group3,
                 from  tt1 order by note desc
                )
  select * from tt2

Comment: You should edit your post (i.e., click the edit button between the share and flag buttons) and add that SQL statement. Make sure you format it so that it looks reasonable. That way you can more easily see where you have a problem. It looks like you have at least one syntax error. Hopefully, your SQL statement execution interface will point you to the problem. Paste all of your output so it is formatted well. Don't be discouraged. If you stick with it, then you'll become a great contributor to SO.

Comment: By your usage of the datediff function, you should add the sql-server tag to your question. If the query works only on, say, newer versions of SQL Server, then you should use whichever specific sql-server tag is most relevant. But my earlier question about the syntax error still stands. I don't think this statement will parse because the of `,` between `group3` and `from`.

Comment: I did what I could.
Is there anyone who can divide the students by percentage?

Comment: Even though you have defined group1 3 different ways, I think I get that the 2nd and 3rd are supposed to be group2 and group3. Edit your post to clear that up. You then give an example that group3 should have 33% of the students. What happened to the earlier definition of 30%? But then the total number of students you intend to put into these groups is 2+2+2 which does not equal 8. Are you sure you want to leave some groups underrepresented in your output?

Comment: i use firebird database
you can use
year(subdate(current_date, to_days(Bdate))) as ages

Comment: because when i divided them by percentage some students Their age is not allowed to be in the 2nd group like suar that's why the number became 6.
don't forget i order them by grade

Comment: yes the output it will be 6 student only

Comment: The one thing that you haven't done is show the output you expect. You gave a list of students. You should include in that table a pseudo column indicating the group that the student should belong to. Then it might be easier to discover the algorithm that you want to implement.

Comment: i edit my question and i add the final result

Comment: What does "divide" mean in this context?

Comment: it means  put them in three groups
group1 contain who has highest grade and Achieves the conditions.and so on

Comment: "As evident all mathematicians can be distributed into three classes: those who mastered counting to three, and those who did not yet"

Comment: I know its a little complicated but is there any help

Comment: I discern at least three distinct usages of _divide_ in your question: _divide in three groups_, _divide by percentage_ and _divide by 5_ (where you actually multiply by five, which still results in three groups), each of which is rather confusing.

Comment: the number of students * percentage
The number of students decreases because some students The condition was not met(Age requirement in each group) after the division so we  re-divide the number of students who meet the requirement.(5)
5 * 35%=1 students who meet the requirement in group1